# Java - Add and remove elements from a dynamic array/list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

I need my array to be dynamic, as long as the user enters/deletes elements. The array can't have the length already defined or ask the user the length. For example the user decides to add 5, the array would be: {5}, then the user adds 34 {5,34}, then deletes 5, {34}.
Is there a way of doing it? i've been trying with list but when i used if the remove one didn't work and when i use switch with this code it says "unreachable statement".
Here's the code so far:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Current  " + list);
            System.out.println("Add more? (1) delete one? (2) exit (3)");
            int a= stdin.nextInt();  
            
            switch(a){
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter: ");
                list.add(stdin.next()); 
                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter: ");
                list.remove(stdin.next());
                break;
                case 3:
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            
        } while (true);
        
        stdin.close();
        System.out.println("List is " + list);
        String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop which you never `break` out of of. Your `break` statements only end the execution of the `switch` not the `do .. while`, hence all code beneath `} while(true);` cannot be reached. You could use a flag `switch = false` and set it to true within your `case 3` and then use `while(!exit)` to make the code reachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use label.
So basically the break in your case 3 only breaks outside switch statement but not outside the do while loop.
You can add a statement before do as below:

```
outerloop:
do{
  switch(a){
  // rest of your logic
  case 3:
  break outerloop;
  }
}
while(true)
```

where outerloop is a label. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your `while` statement.
When you use the `break` keyword, it refers to your `switch` statement.
So you'll never reach the end of your loop.

Try something to implement something to `break` the loop